# JSONRequest.get unresponsive

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to send get requests to the Google Places API with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js">
var googleQuery;
function load() {
    googleQuery = JSONRequest.get(  
       "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=3af0d044d45cd8587d9a3522bc98a95d4f60c6a8&sensor=true&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
       function (googleQuery, value, exception) {
          if (value) {
             processResponse(value);
          }
          else {
             processError(exception);
          }
       }
    ); 
}
</script>
```

And calling the load function in the body onload.

```
  <body onload="load()">
  </body>
```

I am including the src="json2.js" in this `<script>` instead of in its own `<script>`, since I was getting a "JSONRequest is undefined" error...but I am still getting a strange "load is undefined" error.

Am I going about this JSON request correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var googleQuery;
    function load(){
    googleQuery = JSONRequest.get(  
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=3af0d044d45cd8587d9a3522bc98a95d4f60c6a8&sensor=true&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     function (googleQuery, value, exception) {
        if (value) {
            processResponse(value);
        } else {
            processError(exception);
        }
      }
    ); 
   }
</script>
```

You can't have JavaScript code inside a script tag which has the `src` attribute. You should place the inline code on another script tag, otherwise it won't be executed.

Comment: That's the way I had it before, but now when I correct it, I get this error in console: `JSONRequest is not defined
[Break On This Error] googleQuery = JSONRequest.get( `

Comment: Does your `json2.js` contain the function `JSONRequest`? Check to see if the `json2.js` file is being loaded.

Comment: No...it doesn't...that's weird. None of the json2.js files I can find have this function, but its been used in many examples.

Comment: That function seems to be part of [JSONRequest](http://devpro.it/JSON/files/JSONRequest-js.html) object, which you should include before being able use it? However, I suspect this won't work due to same domain origin policy. You should use jQuery to do `JSONP` requests.

Comment: I'll try this path and see, I would use jQuery, but Google Places API isn't supporting `JSONP` anymore :\

Answer (score 2):

Replace the line :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js">
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js"></script>
<script>
```

Your JS code is being ignored since you specified an src attribute.

Comment: That's the way I had it before, but now when I correct it, I get this error in console: `JSONRequest is not defined
[Break On This Error] googleQuery = JSONRequest.get( `

Answer (score 0):

**JSONRequest is more so just a proposal** which browsers can implement at their will (I think Firefox does).

I'm not sure if there are any libraries that can be script sourced to in order to use JSONRequest, but an alternative is to use **flyJSONP** (http://alotaiba.github.com/FlyJSONP/#!/demo).

**flyJSONP** uses YQL (Yahoo Query Language) to do any cross domain post/get, and I highly recommend it (especially for google api's such as oAuth 2.0 and ClientLogin)... and it has a debugger mechanism.

Also, there is **jankyPost** (http://saunter.org/janky.post/).  I have not used it but I'm sure I will and I like its concept.  Its kinda clugy, or well... janky... but read about how it works (short paragraph) and you'll love it and want to build you own perhaps.

--Cody